# Problem with DotNetFiddle and Console.ReadLine that causes a Re-run when pressing ENTER key

Tags: c#, console, readline, .net-fiddle, dotnetfiddle

I have a weird scenario using a [C# online compiler](http://dotnetfiddle.net/MBLRtb) with this code:

```
int randomNumber;
int guess;
int countGuess;
bool correctGuess = false;
bool alreadyCalled = false;
int lastGuess;

public void Main()
{
    if(!alreadyCalled)
    {
        RandomNumberGenerator();
        alreadyCalled = true;
    }
    GuessWhatNumber();
}

private void GuessWhatNumber()
{
    while(!correctGuess)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess the number : ");
        guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
        if(guess > randomNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too High");
            correctGuess = false;
        }
        else if(guess < randomNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too Small");
            correctGuess = false;
        }
        else    
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            correctGuess = true;
            countGuess = 0;
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        
        if(lastGuess != guess)
        {
            countGuess+=1;
            Console.WriteLine("Count of Guess : " + countGuess);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Count of Guess is Still: " + countGuess);
        }
        lastGuess = guess;
    }
}

private void RandomNumberGenerator()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    randomNumber = rand.Next(50);
    Console.WriteLine("Number To Guess : " + randomNumber); 
}
```

The `Random Number Generator` method must be called only once but on that online compiler it keeps calling and calling the method all over again. What am I doing wrong here? Or is it the compiler?

*Dotnetfiddle.net* settings are:

- C#
- Console
- Compiler: .NET 4.7.2
- No nugets packages
- Autorun: NO

Comment: Can you provide direct link to code in the dotnetfiddle? There is no reason to run more times then 1. But maybe you are using `while` instead of `if` and doing different work in your actual code.

Comment: When you say "it keeps calling and calling the method over again" - it will call it each time you run the program, yes. Once the program terminates (at the end of the Main method) all its state is lost. If you believe you're calling the `Main` method multiple times *within one program run* please provide more details.

Comment: without a link to your fiddle we have no way to indicate why you think the code is called multiple times. From the code above this is **impossible**. Anyway your `Main` should be `static`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are doing?  Are you hitting "Run" each time?  I would think each instance of hitting Run starts the code over, resetting `alreadyCalled` to false again which lets `RandomNumberGenerator` get called each time.

Comment: Else if the method `GuessWhatNumber()` is calling it in a loop

Comment: Maybe something in there GuessWhatNumber(); calling one of the main method. You can have a look this method to be sure.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MBLRtb @JonSkeet

Comment: Seems to me also like a bug of dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes only once . But I don't know why it keeps repeating on calling the randomnumbergenerator method

Comment: I've ran your code in IDE and it works fine (after making `Main` method `static` of course) Maybe that's the reason

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski this is really weird for me I'm sorry

Comment: @OlivierRogier it's already on the question sir . Its added.

Comment: @OlivierRogier The code (pretty simple case) was updated to cover whole example now. When you run it via the web, you'll find out it doesn't work there. Probably issue with the web page, that is why OP was raising a link directly to the code. It is providing "unexpected" behaviour.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Just taking a look at the Main in this fiddle, I see that `alreadyCalled` is here totally useless, because the method is called only once...

Comment: It is not about the code, more about the compiler/web service. Try updated fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ek2nuQ

Comment: @Ginxx & @.Tatranskymedved Works fine with *VS2017 C#7.3 .NET Framework 4.7.2 on Windows 10*.

Comment: oww so basically it's because of the online compiler

Comment: I would say it is because of the online app, which rebuild/reruns the code on each input. Compiler is doing the same thing correctly. :)

Answer (score 5):

Once you run the code it is send to the server as request and it'll return the results as text to display in the interface. Once it encounters a point where it requires the users input instead of waiting for the input the full request is send again, but this time with the information from the input window. Then on the backend the full request runs again and automatically adds the input from the users as far as it's known.

In most cases that would be no problem because the same script usually yields the same results. This is a different case however because you added a random element into the script. So each time you input new data everything that happened before runs again and may yield different results.

Comment: I agree with you, You can even see on right bottom `Last Run: 1:45:43 pm`. Everytime, you send a new input and press enter, new time is generated.

Comment: Trying to show my 10-year-old some code yesterday I ran into this exact same use-case. This answer makes total sense and explains it all. I didn't notice the "last run" part in the previous comment but one of the things I did notice was that the console "history" (previous output from my loop saying things like "too high" or "too low") actually CHANGED every time I gave it input. It's because it was replaying the entire "game" with all my previous input and what was "too high" on one run would end up "too low" on the next

Comment: See also [C# console application ReadLine() works in .NET 4.7.2 and not in .NET 5 (on dotnetfiddle)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67138172/3744182) where [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67140047/3744182) by [Sergey Litvinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169635/sergey-litvinov) confirms your explanation of how dotnetfiddle works on .NET Core.