# C# console application ReadLine() works in .NET 4.7.2 and not in .NET 5 (on dotnetfiddle)

Tags: c#, .net, version, .net-fiddle

As I had never written a console application, I thought it was a good idea to start now. If only because of the fact that I find Visual Studio rather sluggish and the idea to be able to test code quickly on one of the playgrounds such as dotnetfiddle seems attractive. The default compiler on dotnetfiddle.net is on .NET 4.7.2 but I noticed that that one choked on the more recent code I borrowed. So I got used to the fact that I have to switch the compiler to .NET 5 to be able to take advantage of for instance niceties such as the $ to format text.

TL;DR

However, I found that a simple `ReadLine()` such as found in the example on https://dotnetfiddle.net/tAJulh doesn't work if you change the compiler to .NET 5. Has something changed in the specification of ReadLine in .NET 5 or is this a limitation of dotnetfiddle? And is there a way around this?

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        // Simply writes the following text to the standard output
        Console.WriteLine("Input some text!");
        
        // Reads text until you hit "enter"; and saves it to the "input"-variable
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        
        // Writes the "input"-variable to the console.
        Console.WriteLine("Your input was: " + input);
        
        // The program will not exit until you hit "Enter".
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can assure you `ReadLine` works, it seems to be a dotnetfiddle issue. If you want a lightweight editor take a look at Visual Studio Code or even LINQPad.

Comment: You can post the issue here: https://dotnetfiddle.uservoice.com/forums/228764--net-fiddle-ideas I agree that you should use something else for testing like LINQPad(but without premium you'll miss debugging and other features).

Comment: Thanks @Crowdcoder, I didn't even think of the fact that I have Visual Studio Code installed, so it appears I'm all set for creating console applications. By the way, I always _do_ test my code in Visual Studio in the end - I only use dotnetfiddle to do quick tests for part of the code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I will - thank you.

Comment: @sandokanfirst we updated it and Console.ReadLine should be working fine now for .NET 3.1\5\6\7\8

Comment: Thanks, @SergeyLitvinov, for the work and the heads-up!

Comment: The example posted on https://stackoverflow.com/a/53813917/2925705 doesn't work with .NET Core and newer. And dotnetfiddle.uservoice.com/forums/ is not available anymore. everything is getting worse :(

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right. Does look like an error on dotnetfiddle and you should report it here: https://dotnetfiddle.uservoice.com/forums/228764--net-fiddle-ideas

As far as i can tell, there is no way around it before they correct the bug.

As some other guys have stated i highly recommend that you get an IDE, this could be visual studio code or the plain visual studio

Personally i enjoy VS code for it's simplicity and it works great for C# and .net

Comment: In this case VS Code does exactly what I need (an editor and compiler to build a console application) so it seems a good fit. But just to clarify: as I understand it, you can't create a GUI with VS Code, can you?

Comment: @sandokanfirst if you need to build a UI you'll have to use Visual Studio (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) there is the free community edition, i'm pretty sure you can build WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) apps in that. You can use it as drag and drop if you just need to play around with it, but if you are serious about the design part i would recommend you learn more about xaml and how the design works.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that `Console.ReadLine` isn't supported at the moment by dotnetfiddle and our's .NET Core implementation. The reason is that we use sandboxes since we need to be safe when we execute user's code. And for .NET 5 we are using docker while for regular .NET 4.7.2\Roslyn we are using AppDomains. In the docker case we are just compiling code and execute it as is. In the AppDomain case we are restricting it by injecting own code on top of user's code.

And since these ways are different, each of them might have some limitations over other. The problem with ReadLine is that when user runs own code, we need to partially execute it, then inject into `Console.In` stream and if something is requested from the stream, then we stop execution and ask user to provide input, and then after input is provided, we need to restart execution again and use that user's input in `Console.In` and repeat it over and over until code is fully executed. It's much easier to inject it for AppDomain so it works fine in .NET 4.7.2 but harder to do it in docker since we don't inject own code there so this feature is missing for now.

**Update at April 2023:**

It should be working fine now as we added implementation for it for .NET 3.1\5\6\7\8

Comment: I'm too much of a beginner in .NET and C# to understand all the particulars of your explanation - specifically the part about AppDomain - but I get the gist of it and it's good to know that this is indeed a limitation as of yet.

Comment: I have a similar situation, what I do is using an intermediate `python` script for launching the built binary with `p = subprocess.Popen` and then I use `p.communicate` to forward the "typed input" (actually a string variable captured inside the `python` script) to the `stdin`.