# .NET fiddle not letting me write in console

Tags: c#, console.readline, .net-fiddle

NOTE: I have figured out that this only affects .NET fiddle if you are using .NET 6. If you aren't using .NET 6 it works fine.

Whenever I use the Console.WriteLine() function on .NET fiddle, it doesn't let me interact with the console. I'm new at coding and .NET fiddle, so it might be a simple fix. I just hope you can figure it out

I've tried just having the Console.WriteLine. I've triple checked I wrote it right. I rewrote the Convert.ToInt32 several times. I looked up to see if anyone else had this problem. I even checked if Console.WriteLine being under the list maker was the problem, it wasn't.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        List<string> shoppingList = new List<string>();
        
        Console.WriteLine("How many items on the list?");
        
        int listLength = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() );
            
        for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            shoppingList.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        
        for(var i = 0; i < shoppingList.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(shoppingList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't let me" - can you elaborate on what that means? If you place your mouse cursor over the console pane at the bottom after running the code, left-click, and then start typing, does nothing happen? Does an error occur? Does it show a `>` prompt after writing the `How many items on the list?` message? Please be mindful that no one but you can see your screen :)

Comment: DotNetFiddle dev here. If you are trying this with .NET Core 6, then it's a known issue for us with how it works internally. There is similar question here with reasoning - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138172/c-sharp-console-application-readline-works-in-net-4-7-2-and-not-in-net-5-on

Comment: @Lilyofluck we updated it and Console.ReadLine should be working fine now for .NET 3.1\5\6\7\8

Answer (score 2):

It's working fine here on my side, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jSyf.jpg). Have you tried cleaning the cookies of your browser? Note that you have to click on the console to type. Also, I fixed your function where it gives the correct size of the `List<string>`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        List<string> shoppingList = new List<string>();
        
        Console.WriteLine("How many items on the list?");
        
        int listLength = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() );
            
        for(var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
            shoppingList.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        
        for(var i = 0; i < shoppingList.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(shoppingList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```