# Why does my random number generated keep changing in .NET Fiddle / dotnetfiddle?

Tags: c#, random, .net-fiddle, dotnetfiddle

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int Winner = r.Next(1, 10);
        bool win = false;
    
        while (win == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game!! Please guess a number between 0 and 10. It is " + Winner + " to win!");
            int Guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
            if (Guess == Winner)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Well done! " + Guess + " is correct!!");
                win = true;`enter code here`
            }
            else if (Guess > Winner)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Guess lower!!");
            }
            else if (Guess < Winner)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Guess higher!!");
            }
        
        }
    
    }
}
```

The logic works, but the random integer changes each time it goes around the loop.

You can see this here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vNrvho

Every time the loop goes around & `Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game!! Please guess a number between 0 and 10. It is " + Winner + " to win!")` is ran again, the random number in the previous `Console.WriteLine` changes as well.

Why does the random number keep changing?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game!! Please guess a number between 0 and 10. 
It is " + Winner + " to win!");  -you show the number and after that you take Guess??

Comment: @KamranMammadov Yep, just to test. I already know what the number is but that number keeps changing.

Comment: This is an invalid question - the random number does not change at all, it's **literally impossible if your code is the above**.

Comment: Can you tell us what your output is? Are you changing values while debugging?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It does, that's the exact code. I could share the dotnetfiddle link if you like? https://dotnetfiddle.net/vNrvho

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary So it asks me to enter a number, and tells me the answer is 8. I type in 7, intentionally getting the answer wrong. It tells me to guess lower. The loop goes around again but this time it tells me the answer is two.

Comment: @Luke You've encountered a dotnetfiddle bug - congrats! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with DotNetFiddle and Console.ReadLine that causes a Re-run when pressing ENTER key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65918816/problem-with-dotnetfiddle-and-console-readline-that-causes-a-re-run-when-pressin)

Answer (score 4):

**This is not an issue with your code, but an issue with .NET Fiddle.**

You can also see the same issue replicated in another fiddle here, which does something similar: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mn7mtT

The way that .NET Fiddle works is unknown to me but it's probably sending console output in a request on every input, changing the previous output somehow server-side and then giving you the *illusion* that the code is running input after input.

However, it's not & it's running the entire code again & again.

This will yield different random values of course and make you think that the value of `Winner` is changing every time while it isn't.

Verify this by noticing the changing `Last Run:` value every time you input a new number or by running the code locally outside of .NET Fiddle.

This happens *regardless of project type or compiler settings* in .NET Fiddle.

The lesson is don't always trust .NET Fiddle!

Comment: @Luke I can confirm this answer (since i'm one of the devs). It's not a bug but more like intention behavior since we need to have all user input (which we might not know). so each time when user gives new input, we have to reexecute code over again (with already entered input)